# Как получить все переменные из файла?

Tags: python, переменные, вывод

Всем доброго времени суток!

предположим, у меня есть такой код:

```
x1 = 1
x2 = 2
x3 = 3
xN = N
```

как мне получить все эти переменные?

что бы в итоге получилось:

```
d = [x1, x2, x3, ...... xN]
```

да, можно вручную перебирать, но когда переменных много - это не очень удобно

Comment: Может, лучше не бороться со следствием, а устранить причину? Почему у вас вообще появились такие переменные?

Comment: Вопрос непонятен. Нужен скрипт, которые пробежится по файлу с исходным кодом на Python и соберёт нумерованные переменные с одинаковым буквенным префиксом и поместит их значия в списки? И даст этим спискам произвольные имена? Потом заменит в исходном файле все такие переменные на соответствующие им списки? Но ведь код написанный для переменных перестанет работать... Получается, требуется также заменить все вхождения порядковых переменных на соответствующие им элементы списков - `x1` на `d[0]`.  Лучше всего скопировать код сюда или дать ссылку на него. И объяснить, что хотите получить в итоге.

Comment: Всем спасибо!. Как я докатился до такой жизни: у меня есть простенький парсер, который парсит (неожиданно) множество сайтов, собирает оттуда данные, и записывает их в виде массивов (списков). Каждому списку присваевается уникальное имя, (не рандомное, записываю в парсер) . Парсятся по 3 данных с каждого сайта. И на выходе мы получаем: список, в который вложены множество списков. и далее стоит задача отсортировать эти списки, и вывести их по возрастанию, основываясь на одном элементе из вложенных списков. Для этого я решил обозначит их всех в один массив и далее сортировать с помощью лямбы

Comment: но тут вышла загвостка: генерится множество переменных, которым присваевается массив, и в конце, для того, что бы их отсортировать , нужно обозначить их в один массив, но простым перечислением это , думаю, слишком неразумно, вот и интересуюсь, есть ли короткий способ)

Comment: Используйте формат YAML вместо простого текста.

Answer (score 3):

Файл `variables.txt` содержит:

```
x1 = 3  
x2 = 4  
x3 = 5  
x4 = 6  
x5 = 7  
x6 = 8  
x7 = 9  
x8 = 10
```

Код:

```
s = []
f = open('variables.txt')
for line in f.readlines():
    s.append(line.rstrip().split('='))
print(s)
f.close()
```

Вывод s:

```
[['x1 ', ' 3'], ['x2 ', ' 4'], ['x3 ', ' 5'], ['x4 ', ' 6'], ['x5 ', ' 7'], ['x6 ', ' 8'], ['x7 ', ' 9'], ['x8 ', ' 10']]
```

Если на до только значения, то тогда так:

```
s = []
f = open('variables.txt')
for line in f.readlines():
    s.append(line.rstrip().split('=')[1])

print(s)
f.close()
```

Вывод s:

```
[' 3', ' 4', ' 5', ' 6', ' 7', ' 8', ' 9', ' 10']
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь! разобрался, все работает

Comment: Еще один вопросик: данный код возвращает список со строчными элементами. А возможно сделать так, что бы первый элемент был строка, а второй - список?)

Comment: @Online поставьте галочку, что ответ правильный

Comment: Кстати, во всех значениях получается лишний пробел слева, хорошо бы его обрезать с помощью `strip`.

Comment: Отсортировать не забудьте

Answer (score -1):

If your file is file.py you can import it and get `__dict__` from object and filter system vars like `__name__`, `__doc__` etc

```
import file

for key, value in file.__dict__.items():
    if not key.startswith('__'):
        print(key, value)
```

You can use `key` and `value` as you prefer. The result will be:

```
x1 3  
x2 4  
x3 5
...
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык